# SSRS - Can someone explain the SSRS Stripline properties to me?

Tags: reporting-services, charts

Specifically the Interval Properties.

No matter what I do I don't get the desired result.
I need to color in 3 shifts of 8h each.

My Chart has the X-Values ranging from 0 to 23.
My earliest shift starts at 5am.
I get the length and offset of each shift through an SQL Query in minutes.

Example Shift 1:

- offset = Datediff from 0 to shiftstart           -> 300 min
- length = Datediff from shiftstart to shiftend    -> 480 min

My intuition tells me that since I have 24 X-Values in my chart, I need to set intervalType to hours or days with either 24 or 1 as value.
I interpret it as "Every Day/24h begin drawing the specified Stripline at its offset-Value with the specified length".

intervalOffsetType would be Minutes.
In my mind, the Offset works in conjunction with the selected IntervalType and since my shift starts at 5am each day, I suspect that intervalOffset needs to be 300.
Which would mean: "Begin drawing the stripline at 5am".

the striplineWidth-property then determines the the width, or rather length of the shift and its type, again, works in conjunction with the IntervalType.

Evidently this is not the case though.

My Settings:
[image]

My Result:
[image]

Can someone explain to me how the Interval Properties work?
I can't find any proper documentation on them either.

Comment: It looks like it's working correctly but is treating your HOUR on the X-axis as a DAY.. Is your data a date/time field? What's the INTERVAL TYPE of the chart?

Comment: it's a datetime field, formatted to display only the hour part. so the values are looking like "10.05.2021 01:00", 10.05.2021 02:00, 10.05.2021 03:00" etc.

Comment: Interval Type of Chart is automatic

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was on the axis-options.

(rightclick x-axis -> properties)

Switching from category to scalar and setting the intervalType produces the desired result.

[image]

I'd need to test it further but for now I think having axis-type set to category applies the stripline to each member of a categorygroup in a chart.